# How to test the method of a private property is called in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have a class which has a private property.

```
import {Socket} from 'socket.io-client';

export class SocketService {
 
  private socket: Socket;
 
  public initializeSocket() {
      if(this.socket) { return; }
      this.socket = // get a new Socket
      this.socket.on('connect', () => this.processConnect() );
  }
  private processConnect() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When write unit test for method `initializeSocket()`, how to validate that the `on` is called? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can't test private methods in a straight way.

There are 3 methods how to test it. It's written in this article [Testing private methods in Typescript](https://dev.to/danywalls/testing-private-methods-in-typescript-3np5)

I'm going to describe 2 of them.

1. The simplest way is to **change signature to protected.**

So `private processConnect()` turns into `processConnect()` (we can write it without the protected signature because it's by default)

2. **You can use array access**.

So if you have a private method like this

```
export class SocketService {
  ....
  private processConnect() {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can access it using array access

```
socketService['processConnect']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it('test socket on',()=>{
  service['socket'] = tempSocket;   // have to initialize it temply as spyOn need a object
  spyOn(service['socket'], 'on');
  service['socket'] = undefined;

  service.initializeSocket();

  expect(service['socket'].on).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```